# in jqgrid select, i'd like to set another edit form field to the selected value then set the selected value to selected label

Tags: jqgrid

in a jqgrid edit form field of type:'select', i'm setting another edit form field with the selected value (the value that is sent to the server) using the editoptions:

```js
dataEvents:[{type:'change',fn:function(e){$('input#STID').val(this.value);}}]}
```

I'd like to then replace the selected value with the selected label. I thought the following would work by adding the statement to the dataEvents function, but it does not:

```js
this.value = this.label;
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of 'change' event `this` (like `e.target`) is the DOM element [HTMLSelectElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980). So `$('option:selected', this).text()` or `$('option:selected', e.target).text()` will get you the text from the selected option.

You should don't modify the `value` property of [HTMLSelectElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980) and just use the text of the selected option as the input for the `<input>` edit field:

```js
dataEvents: [
    {
        type: 'change',
        fn: function () {
            $('input#STID').val($('option:selected', this).text());
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: so.. $('input#STID').val($('option:selected', this).value()); will get the value of the selected option?

Comment: @NelsonM: `$('option:selected', this).value()` is the value of selected option and `$('option:selected', this).text()` it the text of selected option. The value `$('option:selected', this).value()` one can get in more short way (like you used before) but not the text.